# How to get the text (after editing) of TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, textblock

i'm using TreeView in WPF application. i have used complex data to bind as ItemSource. I need to get the modified text after editing in TreeView, because i have to save the xml file with that modified name.

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" ShowRootLines="False"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Margin="0" Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding Result, Converter={StaticResource ResultConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2 0" Name="nodeItem" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

[image]

In above image, i changed the text as "Script1" and now i need an event when i click enter or click next node to rename the respective xml file with modified text.

i have tried Triggers, but could not find feasible event. Please let me know, Is there any possiblities to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you change the text, you have TextBlock, not the TextBox?

Comment: I don't know how it is. i get TextBox instance while entering text in keyDown event.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with your code. The TextBlocks are not editable by me.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

**XAML**

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TreeView Name="treeView" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--<Rectangle Margin="0" Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding Result, Converter={StaticResource ResultConverter}}"/>-->
                        <TextBox Margin="2 0" Name="nodeItem" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        </TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="ConvertToXML" Width="100" Height="50" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SerializedData}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string serializedData = string.Empty;

        public  ObservableCollection<Data> TreeItems {get;set;}

        public string SerializedData
        {
            get
            {
                return serializedData;
            }
            set
            {
                serializedData = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TreeItems=new ObservableCollection<Data>();
            TreeItems.Add(new Data()
            {
                Name = "Root",
                SubItems = new ObservableCollection<Data>()
                {
                  new Data(){Name="Child1"},
                  new Data(){Name="Child2"}
                }

            });

            this.DataContext=this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerializedData = Serialize<ObservableCollection<Data>>(TreeItems);
        }


        public string Serialize<T>(T value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            try
            {
                var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
                {
                    xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, value);
                    return stringWriter.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("An error occurred", ex);
            }
        }


        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }

    public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string name = string.Empty;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        [XmlArrayItem("SubItem")]  
        public ObservableCollection<Data> SubItems { get; set; }


        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```